# Using Template Function properly

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

I am Trying to learn the design rationale for some project,I am trying to run a code given as examples. Here i try to recursively calculate the distance between two points in n dimensions, I can achieve the objective of this code through many other means but i just want to understand this case specifically.(I want to learn Syntax)

Here is my code

```
 template <typename P1, typename P2, int D>
 struct pythagoras
 {
    typedef typename select_most_precise
    <
        typename coordinate_type<P1>::type,
        typename coordinate_type<P2>::type
    >::type computation_type;

    static  double apply(P1 & a, P2 & b)
    {
       double d = get<D-1>(a) - get<D-1>(b);
       return d * d + pythagoras<P1, P2, D-1>::apply(a, b);
    }
};

int main ()
{
   tuple<int,int> mytuple (10,20),two (10,20);
   int f=2;
   double h=pythagoras<tuple<int,int>,tuple<int,int>,int>::apply(mytuple,two,f);
   cout << h;
}
```

Questions:

1- I am Getting the Error  **expected a constant of type ‘int’, got ‘int’**
,How do i resolve it?

2- What does the error actually mean?

3- The code  "Typedef" to "computation_type" this is used to get the type of the variables, How does this work?

Comment: Recursive templates are just like recursive functions in requiring a zero case.  But you can't use any kind of `if` for the zero case.  Instead you need to specialize the template.  Once you fix the syntax details you asked about, you'll need that zero case to make it actually work.

Comment: Thanks,for reminding me  to add the base case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last parameter of your class template is *not* a type! It is a value. That is, you passed `int` where a constant of type `int` like `2` was expected. You'd use the class template like

```
double h=pythagoras<tuple<int,int>, tuple<int,int>, 2>::apply(mytuple, two);
```

Supposedly, there is actually an function which just actually uses this type as an auxiliary tool. At least, I'd expect that there is something like

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
double compute_pythagoras(T1 const& t1, T2 const& t2) {
    return pythagoras<T1, T2, std::tuple_size<T1>::value>::apply(t1, t2);
}
```

I don't see the `computation_type` being used. It seems the *intention* was to determine a suitable type for computations based on the element type of the tuple (or tuple-like entity). The actual choice of whatever it is meant to do is in the definition of `select_most_precise`

Answer (score 1):

You defined `template <typename P1, typename P2, int>`, so when defining a struct sample, you should put a actual literal in it, for example: `pythagoras<tuple<int,int>, tuple<int,int>, 123123>`.

**Remember**: all these types are resolved at **compliation** step, which means that after compliation, everything you put into `< >` brackets must be defined. So you can't put a variable in it.

If you need, you can put `f` into your struct as an constructor's parameter.

Comment: I did that but now i am getting error ‘apply’ is not a member of ‘pythagoras<std::tuple<int, int>, std::tuple<int, int>, 2>’.